# IntelliJ Column Selection using Cursor Keys

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, multiple-columns, textselection, intellij-13

Is it possible to some how setup IntelliJ IDEA so that I can column select with the cursor keys similarly to how I might in Notepad++, Visual Studio, or FlashDevelop.

For instance when I'm typing code I almost always do my navigation solely through use of the keyboard. In the IDEs mentioned previously I can quickly select blocks of code by holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> then tapping <kbd>↑</kbd> to extend my cursor across the lines above. I can then hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and tap <kbd>←</kbd> or <kbd>→</kbd> to quickly jump across words and select the chunk of text I want.

In IntelliJ IDEA I have to constantly enable and disable Column Selection Mode using the <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Insert</kbd> and even then it doesn't quite function as it does in the other IDEs or Text Editors.

Any ideas?

Comment: This **[blog post](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2014/03/intellij-idea-13-1-rc-introduces-sublime-text-style-multiple-selections/)** should be helpful.

Answer (score 217, accepted):

You can do column editing using the `Edit | Column Selection Mode`.

The shortcut to turn it `on/off` is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd>. You navigate with <kbd>Shift</kbd> + arrow keys to select blocks of text.

Comment: I was aware of this mode but it didn't quite provide what I wanted, but it looks like I won't get the desired behavior without writing a plugin myself.

Comment: On Mac the shortcut is Cmd+shift+*

Comment: For some reason on my Mac, Cmd+Shift+8 did not work and I could not figure out why, I remapped that to Control+Option+Command+8 and it worked fine.  I also could not find anything that would prevent that old keymap from working other than possibly a system mapping which overrode it.

Comment: This is the easiest. No need to try out weird combinations of keys

Comment: It's like you didn't even read the question. @JoshuaBarnett Gibolt's answer is what you want.

Comment: Seconding jv110 and his objection to JoshuaBarnett's answer. The poster is clearly aware already of the keyboard shortcut JoshuaBarnett mentions and is looking for a more lightweight way of entering column-editing mode, which is what @Gibolt's answer provides.

Answer (score 93):

#### Multiline Caret (without mouse)

Windows/Linux: <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>CTRL</kbd>(Hold) + <kbd>↑ / ↓</kbd>

Mac: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd>(Hold) + <kbd>↑ / ↓</kbd>

<kbd>ESC</kbd> will end multiline mode.

#### Change Multi-caret Hotkey

To add a custom Keymap, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, type `keymap` and click on the one with `Settings` as subtext. Search for `Clone Caret Above` and `Clone Caret Below`.

I mapped mine to <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>↑ / ↓</kbd>.

#### Bonus

Try holding combinations of <kbd>CTRL</kbd>, <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>, and arrows for improved selection power.

Comment: I believe this should be the correct answer. The accepted answer currently just restates some of the content of the question—but this answer provides true rectangular selection without using the mouse, a la Notepad++.

Comment: On my Mac, the `ALT` key was mapped by default instead of `⌘`. So it was: `ALT` + `ALT` (Hold) + `↑` / `↓`

Comment: You can't just state Windows and macOS and ignore Linux!

Comment: @jv110  true. It's ok to state just `macOS` but can't put  'doze in front of 'nix

Answer (score 68):

It is also possible to select holding `middle mouse key`.

Comment: Brilliant. That s cool :-)

Answer (score 21):

Most convenient way is to:

- MAC: Hold **Option+Shift** and click with mouse.
- Windows: Hold **Alt** and click with mouse.

Comment: As mentioned here(https://stackoverflow.com/a/57262978/1983465), ⇧⌘8 works for me

Comment: Keep in mind, for Mac you only need to hold the Option key all the time

Answer (score 19):

Go to the `Settings | Keymap` and set a shortcut for `Clone Caret Above` and for `Clone Caret Below`

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to have it function similar to that of text editors such as Notepad++ where you can only extend in one direction and the opposite of that direction shrinks it?

Comment: I do not think it is possible. I have not even seen a feature request for that.

Comment: Press Ctrl, then hold Ctrl, it's exactly like you described.

Comment: that was the only solution that works for me. thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 17):

On a mac, to toggle block select on/off:

```
shift command 8
```

<kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>8</kbd>

Comment: muscle memory: go to feature

Answer (score 14):

For me on Mac:

Press once 'option' key, release it, and press and hold it again.
Now navigate with cursor to select desired code.
Press 'Esc' to exit column mode! :)

Answer (score 11):

I think @Meo's answer is the most correct, but if your hand happens to be on the mouse, you can also accomplish this with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left Mouse Button Click</kbd>.  Or look for the `Add Rectangular Selection on Mouse Drag` in the keymap settings.

Comment: Or press Ctrl then hold Ctrl.

Answer (score 11):

In Windows or Linux I press two times <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>

Comment: Click `Ctrl` then quickly press and hold `Ctrl` a second time. Use arrow keys while holding `Ctrl` to add carets/select

Answer (score 1):

For Mac <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>*</kbd> didn't work for me. I changed the keymap to something else and now it works seamlessly.