# Intellij IDEA column selection with Alt key

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, editor

In Intellij IDEA is there a way to enable [column selection mode](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/selecting-text-in-the-editor.html#column_selection) by holding down <kbd>Alt</kbd>, like in other IDEs (for example Visual Studio or Notepad++)?

Currently when pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> IntelliJ uses the multicursor feature, which always results in me having an aditional cursor somewhere where I don't want it.

[image: example image multicursor]

The middle mouse button (hold and drag) does exactly what I want, I just wished I could remap it to the Alt key

Comment: Works fine for me - IJ 2016.3.4, 2017.1.2 EAP; Win 10

Comment: Not an exact answer, but [`Alt+Shift+Insert`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26386163/2646526) toggles `Column Selection Mode`.  You could map that to something more wieldy, like `Alt+Z`.

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-136779

Comment: I've just checked the case (with holding ALT and selecting column) in Intellij IDEA 2017.1.2 and 2016.3.5 on my Linux Mint and it works too. Can it depend on OS, where the IDEA is run?

Comment: @OleksandrTarasenko: Try typing something after you have selected a rectangle. It should always also type somewhere else, because it doesn't remove the cursor that was there when you started the selection.

Comment: @Meo: Thanks, now I can at least subscribe to this issue :D

Comment: @Mikescher it still works fine on my environment even with the conditions you are talking about.

Comment: @OleksandrTarasenko: Hmm I'm currently on my Windows machine. I will try my Linux Laptop this evening, it sounds strange that this should be OS-dependent.

Comment: @OleksandrTarasenko: Ok.. thats embarrassing :D. I've updated IntelliJ on my windows machine and now alt+drag works as expected. Thy must have changed it in one of the last updates. Feel free to post an answer and claim the reward

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In **Preferences > Keymap > Editor Actions** set

`Create Rectangular Selection on Mouse Drag` to `⌥ Click`  (clears old cursors)

Note that it should be **Create** instead of **Add**, and if you like you could set

`Add Rectangular Selection on Mouse Drag` to `⌥ ⇧ Click`  (keeps old cursors)

Answer (score 1):

From the comment, I assume that it's a version issue. Updating the `IDE` may be solve your issue.

Comment: yep, as @OleksandrTarasenko in the comments said: It seems they have fixed it in one of the last updates. Now the selection behaves the same as with other editors.

Answer (score 0):

On Mac, you can choose column selection mode or the temporal shortcut:

- Fn+option+mouse selection
- Cmd shift 8 to mode selection