# Shortcut to uncomment javadoc in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have some comments in this format:

```
/**
 * public class ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     ListNode next;
 *     ListNode(int x) { val = x; }
 * }
 */
```

How to uncomment it?

I have tried <kbd>shift + ctrl + /</kbd>, it leads to:

```
*
 * public class ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     ListNode next;
 *     ListNode(int x) { val = x; }
 * }
```

Comment: you can visit this [document](https://resources.jetbrains.com/storage/products/intellij-idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf) to find your information.

Comment: next time use a block comment instead of converting code to javadoc

Comment: it seems currently, IntelliJ has no shortcut for uncommenting javadoc

Comment: I copied this piece code from other sites... Seems no shortcut could uncomment it directly.

Comment: you can replace all `* ` with nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to convert javadoc to normal text because this is not a common use-case.

You can replace-all "* " with nothing.

Or use column-edit mode in Notepad++ or Sublime Text if you have occurrences of "* " that you don't want to remove.

Answer (score 1):

It was advised to use other tools to edit in *column mode*, but this is not necessary as Intellij IDEA supports it as well. Using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> shortcut you can enable this mode and remove unnecessary comments. More details about column selection is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26386079/intellij-column-selection-using-cursor-keys).

For the future I would advise to use line comment (`//`) as you can easily select several lines and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> to comment them. The same way you could uncomment those as well.

Answer (score 0):

All the shortcuts help are [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-code-editor.html)